# How to grab the last word of a product handle via handlebars in shopify?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, shopify, liquid

a client wants to show the product colour name (which is normally a variant) beside the other variants (in this case, size), however, they have products organized by color in the handle-  (e.g. products/le-blazer-albert-engagee-noir). I'm new to handlebars which i'm using for an ajaxcart. I have the variant printing properly but i'm trying to get the colour, which is hte last word in the handle. Cannot figure it out for the life of me!
this is what I have sofar:

```
  <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">
   
{{product_url}}

</span>
```

and the JS

```
    item = {
        key: cartItem.key,
        line: index + 1, // Shopify uses a 1+ index in the API
        url: cartItem.url,
         product_url: cartItem.handle,
(etc) 
},
      items.push(item);
    });
```

which prints the handle correctly in the DOM, e.g. 'la-chemise-victor-engagee-grise' is shown.
but how do I only print the value of "grise"?

Thank you!!

edit: got it! cartItem.handle.split("-").pop(),

Comment: if it is always the last word, prefixed by a dash, you could just use a regex :)

Comment: got it :) cartItem.handle.split("-").pop(),

Answer (score 1):

cartItem.handle.split("-").pop(),